# How to modify error bar appearance

Tags: gnuplot, error-bars

I would like to make the side lines of the error bars longer, as illustrated in this figure (not created by gnuplot):

[image]

Is there any way to do this without resorting to drawing symbols manually?

Comment: Please explain your question further -  it is not clear enough to answer.

Comment: You've tagged this with Gnuplot, but are you using Gnuplot directly, or via `pgfplots`? If the former, the question is perhaps off topic here.

Comment: I'm using gnuplot, but the graphic was created in inkscape to convey my question (in response to the previous comment).

Comment: @painfulenglish To reply to another commenter, write an @ followed by the username, as I did here (tab completion of usernames is available). As I said though, pure Gnuplot-questions are off topic here I think, [so] would probably be a better place for the question. While we do have a Gnuplot tag here, that is for questions regarding the interaction with LaTeX, such as when using it via `pgfplots`.